# How to extract URL from HTML anchor element using Python3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.2

I want to extract URL from web page HTML source.
Example:

```
xyz.com source code:
<a rel="nofollow" href="example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">Download XYZ</a>
```

I want to extract:

```
example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip
```

How to extract this URL?

I don't understand regex. Also I don't know how to install `Beautiful Soup 4` or `lxml` on Windows. I'm getting errors when I try to install this libraries.

I've tried:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> url = '<a rel="nofollow" href="/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">XYZ</a>'
>>> r = re.compile('(?<=href=").*?(?=")')
>>> r.findall(url)
['/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip']
>>> url
'<a rel="nofollow" href="/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">Download XYZ</a>'
>>> r.findall(url)[0]
'/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip'
>>> a = "https://xyz.com"
>>> print(a + r.findall(url)[0])
https://xyz.com/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip
>>>
```

But just it's a hardcoded HTML sample. How to get the web page source and run my code against it?

Comment: Please explain, what errors you're getting during installation of BS4 or lxml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> url = '<a rel="nofollow" href="/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">XYZ</a>'
>>> ET.fromstring(url).attrib.get('href')
'/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip'
```

This works on this particular example, but `xml.etree.ElementTree` is not an HTML parser. Consider using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup(url).a.get('href')
'/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip'
```

Or, [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(url).attrib.get('href')
'/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip'
```

Personally, I prefer `BeautifulSoup` - it makes html-parsing easy, transparent and fun.

---

To follow the link and download the file, you need to make a full url including the schema and domain ([`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) would help) and then use [`urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve). Example:

```
>>> BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> from urllib.request import urlretrieve
>>> href = BeautifulSoup(url).a.get('href')
>>> urlretrieve(urljoin(BASE_URL, href))
```

---

UPD (for the different html posted in comments):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '<html> <head> <body><example><example2> <a rel="nofollow" href="/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">XYZ</a> </example2></example></body></head></html>'
>>> href = BeautifulSoup(data).find('a', text='XYZ').get('href')
'/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip'
```

Comment: ok. this run. thanks. how to find this code from webpage?

`<a rel="nofollow" <href="/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">XYZ</a>`

Example:

`<html>
<head>
<body><example><example2>
<a rel="nofollow" <href="/example/hello/get/9f676bac2bb3.zip">XYZ</a>
</example2></example></body></head></html>`

UI = User Input
CG = Automatic Changeable for file
ST = STATIC (get)

/UI/UI/ST/CG.zip

Sorry for my bad english