# Extracting URL from source code with Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing

My question is with reference to the following one: 
[How to extract URL from HTML anchor element using Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121127/how-to-extract-url-from-html-anchor-element-using-python3)

What if I do not know the exact URL and just have a keyword which should be present in the URL? How then do I extract the url from the page source?

Comment: Erm... extract all of them and check each in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Use an **HTML parser**.

In case of [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you can pass a [function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) as a keyword argument value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = "test"
data = "your HTML here"
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: x and word in x):
    print(a['href'])
```

Or, a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
import re

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(word)):
    print(a['href'])
```

Or, using a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select('a[href^="{word}"]'.format(word=word)):
    print(a['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regular expression

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?i)href=["\']([^\s"\'<>]+)', content)
```